# Is there a Java semaphore across JVMs?

Tags: java, semaphore

The C# Semaphore class has a mode where you name it and the semaphore can be accessed by multiple applications on the same machine. Does Java have this?

Answer (score 1):

*We need to go deeper* - in [hazelcast](/questions/tagged/hazelcast) there is a distributed semaphore that works across the whole network: [`ISemaphore`](http://www.hazelcast.com/docs/2.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/ISemaphore.html). But that's not quite what you want and the simple answer is: no, Java has no such facility.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support this functionality.

However, CLIPC, an open-source Java library, links to a DLL to offer native semaphore features.

http://clipc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

To chime in with yet another option, you could use [an external Redis server](http://redis.io/) with [the Jedis client library](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/README.md) and a [technique like this](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/08/06/a-distributed-mutex-and-semaphore-using-redis/) to construct a semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing RMI based RPC it would be trivial to construct a shared synchronizer. Wrapping a `java.util.concurrent` semaphore with a remote object would work fine.  Depending on your use case... This isn't the most performance sensitive thing you could do, especially if you are talking about shared Jvms on the same node.